# C# Read Cursor inside refcursor(Oracle)

Tags: c#, oracle

I've got an oracle stored function that returns sys_refcursor as an out parameter.
It's structure belike

### Object

- param1
- param2
- param3
- **param4_list(cursor)**

I want to get param1-3 values into datatable1 and param4_list(cursor) values into datatable2 using C#. Any suggestions? If possible, show examples please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for nested cursors in ODP.NET. You'll have to take a different approach. e.g. returning the rows as XML or JSON instead of in a nested cursor. 
Read my question on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:9537644600346225613).

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.